# JQuery toggle() behaving non-linear

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm creating some content that stays hidden until a list item is pressed on.

Here is the code snippet

```
// html
<li class="skill-list">test</li>
<div class="skill-expand">
    test content
</div>

// css
.skill-expand{
    border-radius: 10px;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
}

// script
$('.skill-list').bind('click', function(event) {
    $(this).next().toggle(1000);
});
```

This works the way I want it too, except the animation acts weird... The expansion and collapse of the next item is very non-linear. What I mean is when its being turned on, it'll grow a bit, shrink a bit then grow to max... When its turned off its the same issue...

Comment: A `<li>` and a `<div>` cannot be siblings in any valid HTML document.

Comment: Are you trying to make it look like this? http://jsfiddle.net/aGj9Y/ Seems like 100% width is just growing as the text is added to the container.

Comment: @Jon I'm not sure what the implications of your comment is Jon. My JQuery code runs fine...

Comment: @brbcoding Yes that is exactly what I'm looking for, however in my chrome browser I'm getting stutters in the animation

Answer (score 0):

Could not find a proper answer, instead switched to a better solution:

1. Set height of div to 0
2. Set display to block Set
3. Set overflow to hidden
4. In your jQuery code, just change the height px using the .animate()

This eliminates all lag